# SQL Stored Procedure not recognising column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015

I have a very basic login for a school admin system. The stored procedure needs to take a username and password. It looks up the user ID on a 'Person' table and determines if the user is a teacher or administrator. It then, accordingly looks up either the Teacher or Administrator tables to match the password. The problem I am having is that it doesn't seem to recognise the column name "Type" in the Person table, nor the "Password" column names in the other 2 tables. Here is my SQL command. (NB: It is only the column names mentioned in IF statements that it is not recognising. Everything else seems fine). Appreciate any assistance you can give. Many thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Login
(@ID INT, @PW TEXT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @USERTYPE INT
SET @USERTYPE = 0
SELECT Type FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID
IF (Type = 'Teacher')
BEGIN
    (SELECT Password FROM dbo.Teacher WHERE @ID = TID)
    IF (@PW = Password)
    BEGIN
        SET @USERTYPE = 1
        END
        END
ELSE IF (Type = 'Administrator')
BEGIN
    (SELECT Password FROM dbo.Administartion WHERE @ID = AID)
    IF (@PW = Password)
    BEGIN
        SET @USERTYPE = 2
        END
        END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SET @USERTYPE = 0
END
END
```

Comment: Please add a tag for your database system. Note that the [tag:sql] tag is for the standard SQL language. Also, note that in general, you should *not* be storing passwords in plain text in the database.

Comment: Type and Password are reserved keywords. If you are using Microsoft SQL Server you need to enclose them in square braces: `[Type]` and `[Password]` or if you are using MySQL you need to use ticks ` instead.

Comment: I have tried square braces but am still getting the same errors. It seems strange that the column names are accepted in all other uses except the IF-statements

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` and `t-sql` based on the used syntax

Comment: You'll have to assign the type to a variable: `SET @type = (SELECT Type FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID)`. So after that you can use `IF(@type = 'Teacher')`

Comment: I tried your suggestion @diiN_ and it came up with a new error: "The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables"

Comment: a) why is the `Type` column of type `TEXT` or `NTEXT`? Unless you need to store up to 2GB of text information, use `NVARCHAR(xyz)` instead with `xyz` being the maximum length. In your case `NVARCHAR(128)` should be more than enough. b) the error says it all. You can not use `TEXT` or `NTEXT` for variables in T-SQL. Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead, but do what I said in a) first.

Comment: @DaveOli try some thing like this `(SELECT @type =Type FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID). So after that you can use IF(@type = 'Teacher')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're pretty new to SQL, aren't you? Because that's not how queries work:

```
SELECT Type FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID
```

This *does* select the `Type` value, but it *returns* it as one result set of the Stored Procedure. It doesn't *store* it anywhere.

That's why the following doesn't work:

```
IF (Type = 'Teacher')
```

There is no variable `Type` defined anywhere for SQL to know what to do with it (apart from the fact that it is a reserved word). You need to store the result of the query in a variable.

```
SET @type = (SELECT TOP 1 [Type] FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID)
```

The `TOP 1` clause is important to avoid problems with multiple records returned. It shouldn't be possible if ID is the primary key, but better be safe than sorry.

You need to restructure the entire thing. One example could be:

```
DECLARE @USERTYPE INT
SET @USERTYPE = 0

DECLARE @type NVARCHAR(128)
SET @type = (SELECT TOP 1 [Type] FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID)

IF (@type = 'Teacher')
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Teacher WHERE @ID = TID AND [Password] = @PW)
        SET @USERTYPE = 1
END ELSE IF (@type = 'Administrator') 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Administartion WHERE @ID = AID AND [Password] = @PW)
        SET @USERTYPE = 2
END
```

That being said I guess you should also restructure your database to have one common table that stores information about both teachers and administrators. What's the reason for having two separate tables? Put common information (like login data, names, addresses, etc.) into the person table and only specific information (like which subjects does a teacher teach) into separate tables, connecting them by the person ID.

In your current scheme, what happens if you have a person that's both a teacher and an admin?

---

You said there's no person that's both teacher and admin, so you can simplify the entire query a bit:

```
DECLARE @USERTYPE INT
SET @USERTYPE = 0

SELECT @USERTYPE = UserType FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS UserType FROM dbo.Teacher WHERE @ID = TID AND [Password] = @PW)
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS UserType FROM dbo.Administartion WHERE @ID = AID AND [Password] = @PW)
) tmp
```

Please note that this only works if `ID` is unique across both tables.

Comment: yes I'm very new to SQL. Thankyou for your suggestion. Trying it now.

Comment: Please note that you need to adapt the type of `@type` to the actual column type. If it is `TEXT`, `NTEXT` or the like, use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead and really think about restricting the type in the table to something useful. Unless you want to store up to 2GB of text, there's *absolutely no reason* to use `TEXT` or `NTEXT`.

Comment: OK, have tried your suggestion but it is not liking the 'THEN' keywords

Comment: What I said above goes for the parameters of the stored procedure and all other columns as well! Really think about how much information you need to store within the table fields. Passwords, type information, use names and the like *should never be of type `TEXT`*! That being said, there are database systems that only have the `TEXT` type (like SQLite), but SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql are **not** among these - use proper typing here.

Comment: @DaveOli Oh, sorry about the `THEN`. Remove it. I was thinking in another language right now...

Comment: Read a book. Your table design sucks - having separate Teacher and Administrator tables to store the passwords - and storing the passwords in clear text - are two issues. One shows zero knowledge of databases, the second shows legally questionable gross neglect for basic computer security issues.

Comment: With regards to your earlier questions, I am not in control of the database itself. This is for an assignment and I need to design around the existing database unfortunately. There are no instances of teachers being administrators.

Comment: @DaveOli Well then, tell the person in charge that their database design "is not optimal", to say the least. :-)

Comment: @TomTom I am reading a book. One that supplied me with the current project I am working on, which is leaving me to design a system around a pre-existing database/table system, and has not yet reached the section on password encryption.

Comment: Please don't `COUNT` when all you care about is the difference between "no rows" and "one or more rows" - use `EXISTS`.

Comment: NOONE encrypts passwords. This allows decrypting. Use hashes. And read a PROPER book - one about database basics.

Comment: If there's no person that's both teacher and admin, you can simplify the entire query a bit - I'm editing...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, sorry, I was trying to be quick. Changed the queries to using `EXISTING`.

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is a reserved keyword in `SQL`, so use square brackets.

Also, you need to take value of `[Type]` in a variable so that you can later refer it.

```
DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT @Type=[Type] FROM dbo.Person WHERE @ID = ID

IF (@Type = 'Teacher')
```